# Cannot run escaped Windows command line on python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, escaping

When I run the following command on a Windows command prompt, no problem.

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\SnapBackup\app\snapbackup.jar" main
```

I tried running the command in a python script. It fails. My python script is like this;

```
import os
command_line = 'java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\SnapBackup\app\snapbackup.jar" main'
os.system(command_line)
```

The error message received is

> Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SnapBackuppp\snapbackup.jar

Can someone help? Thanks.

I am using python 2.7.9

Comment: Did you notice that the error message has 3 letters 'p' at the end of SnapBackup? Is this a typo in the question or in the python file?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the python code. Just checked again. I copied and pasted the error message from pycharm IDE. I really don't know why there are 3 p. Strange.

Comment: backslashes! Use forward slashes or escape the backslash like \\

Comment: Hey! That's the answer. Thanks! Answer is `command_line = 'java -jar "C:/Program Files (x86)/SnapBackup/app/snapbackup.jar" main'`. Please copy it down, post it as answer and I will give you the votes. You deserve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using backslashes in the command line. In python better use forward slashes or escape the backslashes with a backslash

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

```
command_line = 'java -jar "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SnapBackup\\app\\snapbackup.jar" main'
```

### Explanation

Windows uses backslashes ("\") instead of forward slashes ("/"). This isn't an issue when using the Windows command line itself, but causes problems when using other tools that process *escape sequences*. These escape sequences each start with a backslash. Typically, strings in Python process them.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

If you look closely at your error...

> Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Program Files (x86)\SnapBackuppp\snapbackup.jar

...you'll notice that it says SnapBack**uppp**, instead of SnapBack**up\app**

#### What happened?

The "\a" was being processed as the ASCII Bell (BEL) escape sequence (see link above). The other characters with a backslash in front of them weren't affected, because they don't correspond to an escape sequence. (That is, the `\P` in `C:\Program Files (x86)`, etc.)

To avoid processing the `\a` as the Bell character, we need to escape the *backslash itself*, by typing `\\a`. That way, the second backslash is treated as a "normal" backslash, and the "a" gets read as expected.

You can also tell Python to use a *raw* (unprocessed) string by doing this:

`command_line = r'java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\SnapBackup\app\snapbackup.jar" main'`

(Note the `r` just before the first quote character.

Alternatively, you could also use forward slashes.

`command_line = 'java -jar "C:/Program Files (x86)/SnapBackup/app/snapbackup.jar" main'`

However, this may not work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `subprocess` instead of `os.system`  https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.  Also, like others before me have noted, you have unescaped backslashes.  Use `os.path.join` to remedy the situation:

```
import subprocess, os
jarPath = os.path.join('c:', 'Program Files (x86)', 'SnapBackup', 'app', 'snapbackup.jar')
command_line = ['java', '-jar', jarPath, 'main']
subprocess.call(command_line)
```

Comment: Strange. The same error appears. But thanks. Upvoted.

Comment: Just noticed the comments under the question. Other people have faster fingers than I do :).  I've updated my answer to provide a cross platform way of doing it.  Using ``os.path.join`` will make it so you don't have to worry about what kind of slash is appropriate to use.