# os.system not properly handling escaped Windows path

Tags: python, windows, path, escaping

Can someone please explain why this code:

```
import os

t = '"X://Program Files/MPC-HC/mpc-hc64.exe"' + ' ' + '"X://Movies/test play/test play - 720p Version/' + "test-play1" + '.mkv"'
os.system(t)
print t
```

throws:

```
'X://Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

but directly pasting

```
"X://Program Files/MPC-HC/mpc-hc64.exe" "X://Movies/test play/test play - 720p Version/test-play1.mkv"
```

into cmd works?

Comment: Windows uses backslash "\\" as a path separator, not forward slash "/".

Comment: @DYZ Unlikely the issue.

Comment: not an issue, tested, python does the conversion i guess

Comment: @DYZ: Windows uses both, though you sometimes need to quote forward slash based paths to avoid them being interpreted as switches. Try it. `dir C:/Users` fails because of the switch interpretation, but `dir "C:/Users"` is perfectly happy.

Comment: as i wrote above, pasting directly into cmd works, python version doesn't

Comment: Not really the point, but `os.system` is terrible. Any reason not to use, say, `subprocess.call` (or related) with `list` based invocation to let Python handle the issues with embedded whitespace in paths/arguments?

Comment: tried both subprocess.call and subprocess.Popen, got the same error as above, but i am still more curious about os.system...

Comment: apparently the blank in the path is the problem, did you check the manual how to handle such paths?

Comment: @DYZ, no, that's 23 years out of date, since 1995 Windows accepts '/' too. The issue here is raw-string or escaping the whitespace inside *"Program Files"*

Comment: There are tons of duplicates on SO, here's one of many: [Cannot run escaped Windows command line on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448153/cannot-run-escaped-windows-command-line-on-python). We should pick which duplicate is canonical

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run escaped Windows command line on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448153/cannot-run-escaped-windows-command-line-on-python)

Comment: @smci This is surely not a dup of that question. The problem addressed there is caused by a backslash. The OP's problem is not.

Comment: @smci no, that i definitely not the problem

Comment: import os;
print(os.getenv('comspec','unknown'));
t = '"C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"';os.system(t); this program prints the path of the command interpreter and starts interet explirer. Does it work on your system? i added a ; after each line of the program . replace it by a line break

Comment: `os.system` expects you to know how to use your shell, i.e. you are expected to read the help text from `cmd /?`. If you read that help, this problem should be obvious. `cmd /c` strips the first and last quote off in your case (i.e. the "old behavior" scenario). If you use `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True` and the command passed as a string (do not use an args list with `shell=True`), then this shouldn't be a problem because it quotes the whole command, which of course you can also do manually with `os.system`.

Comment: @miracle173 yes it works. About blank in the path, running the same command manually in cmd works, so i don't think that's the issue here

Comment: but from your error message one can see that the blank is the issue. What was the comspec it printed out and what was the path to your internet explorer you used?

Comment: In the error message only the path until the first blank is taken, even idf

Comment: solved using subprocess.Popen, but i'm still curious what's happening with os.system(). @miracle173 comspec is C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: @alexstx, I already told you what's happening. When you execute a command such as `cmd.exe /c "X:/Program Files/MPC-HC/mpc-hc64.exe" "X:/Movies/test play/test play - 720p Version/test-play1.mkv"`, CMD will strip off the first and last quotes. This is the "old behavior". To get around this, the entire command line has to be passed in double quotes, e.g. `os.system('"%s"' % t)`.

Comment: This is clearly explained in CMD's help from `cmd /?`. Please read it.

Comment: @eryksun i already passed it in double quotes and still getting the same results...

Comment: I can only go off your question as it's written, which doesn't show that you're quoting the entire command line. Edit your question in response to show how you've modified your code and the current error message.

Comment: Also, it's poor form for forward slashes to be doubled anywhere except at the beginning of a UNC path. That shouldn't be a problem here, however. CMD and the Windows API both ignore repeated slashes unless they're at the beginning of the path. But they shouldn't have to ignore a useless, redundant path separator.